# How to find source URL (javascript) chrome /developer

Tags: javascript, php

The page in in question is at http://www.ebay.com/itm/2004-Toyota-Land-Cruiser-/172629634591

I did click the "Vehicle history" report botton then view full history button, where does it load that information from? It's not an iFrame, I checked the source code. Thank you.

I checked the source HTML But the vehicle history report is not in the HTML source. Thank you kindly.

Comment: "POWERED BY autocheck"

Answer (score 0):

It loads in a javascript file. This file has a single function - one of the parameters is the content of the tab. From your example:

http://sgwesb.ebay.com/?X-EBAY-SVC-SERVICE=vhr_experian&ptn=e&ha=AQAAAVuDgFujAANKVEVIVDA1Slg0MjA1NDkwODo6MTQ5MjU2OTYyMjE2NSLGLFTMdYL8tU06Kw7DGp4EkQac&json=1&vin=JTEHT05JX42054908&seller=domingocabrera09&item=172629634591&cb=jQuery170906996250157976_1492569651760&_=1492569664976

Comment: thank you but hwo did you find that? is there a php way to find it .. thanks

Comment: Just using Chrome developer tools. There's no definitive PHP tool to introspect a website like Chrome dev-tools can.

Comment: thanks i came up with this code but i used single qoute so i dnot have to escape special characters but it still not working

Answer (score -2):

See this image , it call ajax
[network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQmmm.png)